# Including high-density vectorial images in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

A lot of the figures that I'm creating for work include audio signals at high sampling frequencies and, thus, characterized by a lot of data points.
Therefore, in most of the cases, I cannot simply import all the data points through a bunch of `tsv` files in my tikz figures (this is the standard way to save the data points to import in the figure when using `matlab2tikz`).

In order to accommodate for this high-density plots, I changed the function `matlab2tikz` in a way that I save the axis content of my images (e.g. a waveform with lots of data points) as a `png` file;
I then include this file in the `groupplot` environment of my `tikzpicture` using the command

```
\addplot graphics [xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1] {sig_raster.png};
```

where the image is, for instance, [image]

This has worked kind-of OK so far, but I was wondering if a better solution exist, given that the image is raster and I'd rather having a vectorial one.

For instance, If I save the content within the axes of my MATLAB figure as an EPS or a PDF file, I'd like to be able to include such PDF/EPS files in `groupplot` using the same `addplot graphics`; unfortunately that's not possible.

I was thinking to use some workaround like drawing the axes with `groupplot`, creating a rectangle or a node spanning the whole axes' area and, inside that, calling the `includegraphics` command, something like

```
\draw(axis cs:0,-1) rectangle (axis cs:1,1) node[midway] {\includegraphics{sig_vector.eps}};
```

(you can find the vector image [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=44501104171568977798))

However, by doing this, it's more difficult to correctly associate the limits of my plot with the axes (what I was doing using `graphics [xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1]` in the raster case).

Is there a better and less painful way to do this?

Comment: `\addplot graphics` is just a wrapper around `includegraphics`, so it supports the same file formats. After converting your `sig_vector.eps` to a PDF using `epstopdf`, I can use it in an `\addplot` command without problems. Does this not work for you? What error message do you get?

Comment: I found out that I was placing `\usepackage{epstopdf}` before `\usepackage{tikz}`and that created some problems with the EPS files.
Regarding the PDF, I realized that I saved from MATLAB using a wrong command (either because I saved it in another format but with suffix pdf, or because I used the wrong parameters, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367738/pdf-output-from-matlab-and-inclusion-in-latex)

I guess we can close the thread.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue turned out to not be related to the "addplot graphics" command.